# Stored procedure - list of strings as an out variable. How do I do this?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a pl/sql procedure that will be called from a web application. It needs to return a list of Strings. How would I do this?

```
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.1.0.6.0 - Production
PL/SQL Release 11.1.0.6.0 - Production
"CORE   11.1.0.6.0  Production"
TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.1.0.6.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.1.0.6.0 - Production
```

Comment: Can you show us your code up to now? I have close to zero experience with PL/SQL but can't you return a result set (a single column of strings)?

Comment: Add the script of the PL/SQL proc. I'll be forced to vote to close otherwise.

Comment: use ref cursor to return result set from oracle db and use iterator on this result set from web app say java.

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this would be to have the PL/SQL function return an open cursor and have the web app iterate through the cursor to obtain its values:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SOME_FUNC(pin_Some_param IN NUMBER)
    RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
IS
  cCursor  SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN cCursor FOR SELECT A_FIELD FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE SOME_FIELD = pin_Some_param;

  RETURN cCursor;
END SOME_FUNC;
```

The details of 'have the web app iterate through the cursor' are, of course, highly dependent on the languages being used in the web app.

Note also that the web application is responsible for closing the cursor.

Best of luck.